# What operations breaks the hardlinks?

Tags: windows, hardlink

I have a file "a.txt" and its hardlink "ha.txt". If I open either of those files in notepad and save any changes it would appear in both files as they are still linked. But if I overwrite (copy) a.txt with another file with same name the hardlink breaks. What other operations do this?

Also, can I use it to backup a folder? Since if I ever change (overwrite) "a.txt" the hardlink automatically breaks and I have 2 copies. But because it depends on what I use to overwrite it (notepad certainly won't work) it ultimately depends on what operations in windows "breaks" the hardlinks and make copies?

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/306548/windows-7-mklink-hard-links-attributes-expected-contents-do-not-affect?rq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/907431/editing-the-hardlink-doesnt-edit-the-original-file/961953#961953

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that deletes and recreates the target file will break the link.  Some applications will do this, some won't.  I don't think there's any way to predict this in advance.

Hard links are not a sensible backup mechanism, since there is only ever one copy of the file.  Backups should always be to a different physical disk, anyway, in case the entire disk fails.

Comment: Also, although obvious, if you modify the content of one "file", the hardlinked "backup" will be modified. Usually, you don't want your backup to change after the backup, don't you ?

Comment: See also this answer for some examples (especially in the comments): http://superuser.com/a/306832/242652

Comment: When using hard links as part of backup strategy, you don't use the hard links as your backup, but as a way of efficiently storing multiple copies of your backup from different dates - unchanged files are hard links that occupy no space.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that rewrites the filename will break the link. Modifying the file contents will not, nor will changing the filename metadata.

Comment: Could you clarify "rewrites the filename"? Renaming a file does not affect the hardlink.

Comment: One has to separate the concepts of "file name" and "file contents" in order to understand how hard links work. People have been conditioned by FAT/VFAT for so long into thinking that they are one and the same. The "file name" (which in reality is just a hard link) points to the "file contents" stored in inodes on disk. Removing and recreating the hard link in effect "rewrites" it.